# Implementing the Rprop algorithm in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, theano

I am trying to implement the resilient backpropagation optimizer for Keras ([link](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS06/Musterererkennung/Paper/rprop.pdf)), but the challenging part was being able to perform an update on each individual parameter based on whether its corresponding gradient is positive, negative or zero. I wrote the code below as a start towards implementing the Rprop optimizer.  However, I can't seem to find a way to access the parameters individually. Looping over `params` (as in the code below) returns `p, g, g_old, s, wChangeOld` at each iteration which are all matrices.

Is there a way where I could iterate over the individual parameters and update them ? It would also work if I could index the parameter vector based on the sign of its gradients.

```
class Rprop(Optimizer):
    def __init__(self, init_step=0.01, **kwargs):
        super(Rprop, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.init_step = K.variable(init_step, name='init_step')
        self.iterations = K.variable(0., name='iterations')

        self.posStep = 1.2
        self.negStep = 0.5
        self.minStep = 1e-6
        self.maxStep = 50.

    def get_updates(self, params, constraints, loss):
        grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
        self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]

        shapes = [K.get_variable_shape(p) for p in params]
        stepList = [K.ones(shape)*self.init_step  for shape in shapes]
        wChangeOldList = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]
        grads_old = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]

        self.weights = stepList + grads_old + wChangeOldList
        self.updates = []

        for p, g, g_old, s, wChangeOld in zip(params, grads, grads_old, 
                                                                  stepList, wChangeOldList):
            change = K.sign(g * g_old)

            if change > 0:
                s_new = K.minimum(s * self.posStep, self.maxStep)
                wChange = s_new * K.sign(g)
                g_new = g

            elif change < 0:
                s_new = K.maximum(s * self.posStep, self.maxStep)
                wChange = - wChangeOld
                g_new = 0

            else:
                s_new = s
                wChange = s_new * K.sign(g)
                g_new = p

            self.updates.append(K.update(g_old, g_new))
            self.updates.append(K.update(wChangeOld, wChange))
            self.updates.append(K.update(s, s_new))

            new_p = p - wChange

            # Apply constraints
            if p in constraints:
                c = constraints[p]
                new_p = c(new_p)

            self.updates.append(K.update(p, new_p))
        return self.updates

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'init_step': float(K.get_value(self.init_step))}
        base_config = super(Rprop, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Comment: Don't you need K.switch(K.equal(change,0)...) here instead of if/elif/else?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for an RProp algorithm in Keras as well and found this question.  I took the liberty of adapting your code to my purpose and post it back here now.  So far it seems to work quite well, but I didn't test it extensively.

Disclaimer: I'm very new to keras but have a lot of experience with theano (and blocks).  Further I tested this only with theano as a backend, but not tensorflow.

```
class RProp(Optimizer):
    def __init__(self, init_alpha=1e-3, scale_up=1.2, scale_down=0.5, min_alpha=1e-6, max_alpha=50., **kwargs):
        super(RProp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.init_alpha = K.variable(init_alpha, name='init_alpha')
        self.scale_up = K.variable(scale_up, name='scale_up')
        self.scale_down = K.variable(scale_down, name='scale_down')
        self.min_alpha = K.variable(min_alpha, name='min_alpha')
        self.max_alpha = K.variable(max_alpha, name='max_alpha')

    def get_updates(self, params, constraints, loss):
        grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
        shapes = [K.get_variable_shape(p) for p in params]
        alphas = [K.variable(numpy.ones(shape) * self.init_alpha) for shape in shapes]
        old_grads = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]
        self.weights = alphas + old_grads
        self.updates = []

        for param, grad, old_grad, alpha in zip(params, grads, old_grads, alphas):
            new_alpha = K.switch(
                K.greater(grad * old_grad, 0),
                K.minimum(alpha * self.scale_up, self.max_alpha),
                K.maximum(alpha * self.scale_down, self.min_alpha)
            )
            new_param = param - K.sign(grad) * new_alpha
            # Apply constraints
            if param in constraints:
                c = constraints[param]
                new_param = c(new_param)
            self.updates.append(K.update(param, new_param))
            self.updates.append(K.update(alpha, new_alpha))
            self.updates.append(K.update(old_grad, grad))

        return self.updates

    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'init_alpha': float(K.get_value(self.init_alpha)),
            'scale_up': float(K.get_value(self.scale_up)),
            'scale_down': float(K.get_value(self.scale_down)),
            'min_alpha': float(K.get_value(self.min_alpha)),
            'max_alpha': float(K.get_value(self.max_alpha)),
        }
        base_config = super(RProp, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Important notes:

- RProp is often not included in machine learning libraries for a reason: It does not work at all unless you use full-batch learning.  And full-batch learning is only useful if you have a small training set.
- Adam (Keras builtin) outperforms this RProp algorithm.  Maybe because that's just how it is, or maybe because I made a mistake :)

A few comments about your code (referring to your original variable names):

- `wChange` is never used across iterations, so you don't need to store those in permanent variables.
- `change > 0` does not do what you think it does because `change` is a tensor variable.  What you want here is a element-wise comparison, use `K.switch()` instead.
- You used `maxStep` twice instead of using `minStep` the other time.
- The situation where `change` is zero is negligible, since that almost never happens in practice.
- `g_new = 0` and `g_new = p` are both completely bogus and should be `g_new = g` as in the first if branch.

Comment: Could you explain how to use this code?  Should I add it to the source code of the Keras or just include this in my own project. But this is a class, what should I do? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HongCheng Do not add it to Keras, instead just add it to your own project. Then when you have built your model, call `mymodel.compile(optimizer=RProp(...), ...)`. To make it also work when reloading the model after saving, you probably also have to use the `custom_objects` argument to `load_model()`.

Comment: @jlh I added the file (as `rprop.py`) to the codebase where all the `.py` optimizers are stored and I tried to reference it in my model as `optimizer=rprop` but I think I'm missing an instantiation step, what should I do? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to keras and Python but I modified the code above for my purposes a bit.

It is incredibly fast and simple algorithm due to using full-batch learning and partial derivatives. In my tests it outperformed all other backpropagation algorithms, including Adam. I tested it with Tensorflow and CNTK as a backend.

Modified Rprop without Weight-Backtracking:
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/df9c/6a3843d54a28138a596acc85a96367a064c2.pdf

```
class iRprop_(Optimizer):
def __init__(self, init_alpha=0.01, scale_up=1.2, scale_down=0.5, min_alpha=0.00001, max_alpha=50., **kwargs):
    super(iRprop_, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.init_alpha = K.variable(init_alpha, name='init_alpha')
    self.scale_up = K.variable(scale_up, name='scale_up')
    self.scale_down = K.variable(scale_down, name='scale_down')
    self.min_alpha = K.variable(min_alpha, name='min_alpha')
    self.max_alpha = K.variable(max_alpha, name='max_alpha')

def get_updates(self, params, loss):
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
    shapes = [K.get_variable_shape(p) for p in params]
    alphas = [K.variable(K.ones(shape) * self.init_alpha) for shape in shapes]
    old_grads = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]
    self.weights = alphas + old_grads
    self.updates = []

    for p, grad, old_grad, alpha in zip(params, grads, old_grads, alphas):
        grad = K.sign(grad)
        new_alpha = K.switch(
            K.greater(grad * old_grad, 0),
            K.minimum(alpha * self.scale_up, self.max_alpha),
            K.switch(K.less(grad * old_grad, 0),K.maximum(alpha * self.scale_down, self.min_alpha),alpha)    
        )

        grad = K.switch(K.less(grad * old_grad, 0),K.zeros_like(grad),grad)
        new_p = p - grad * new_alpha 

        # Apply constraints.
        if getattr(p, 'constraint', None) is not None:
            new_p = p.constraint(new_p)
        self.updates.append(K.update(p, new_p))
        self.updates.append(K.update(alpha, new_alpha))
        self.updates.append(K.update(old_grad, grad))

    return self.updates

def get_config(self):
    config = {
        'init_alpha': float(K.get_value(self.init_alpha)),
        'scale_up': float(K.get_value(self.scale_up)),
        'scale_down': float(K.get_value(self.scale_down)),
        'min_alpha': float(K.get_value(self.min_alpha)),
        'max_alpha': float(K.get_value(self.max_alpha)),
    }
    base_config = super(iRprop_, self).get_config()
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Comment: I tried to use it. But i get error: TypeError: get_updates() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)