# "Unknown RProp Optimizer" in Keras

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a model using the RProp optimizer as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768411/implementing-the-rprop-algorithm-in-keras) and [this question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324140/how-to-change-keras-optimizer-code).

I downloaded the `rprop.py` script from [this Github repository](https://github.com/ntnu-ai-lab/RProp) and added it to my Keras/tf codebase, at `C:\mini\envs\aiml3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\optimizer_v2`.

In my R script (running in RStudio), I run the following to create my model:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = "sigmoid", input_shape = c(2)) %>% #logistic, input
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid") #output

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = "rprop",
  loss = "binary_crossentropy",
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)
```

but I am thrown an error with the following traceback:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Unknown optimizer: rprop

Detailed traceback: 
  File "C:\mini\envs\aiml3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\mini\envs\aiml3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 251, in compile
    self._set_optimizer(optimizer)
  File "C:\mini\envs\aiml3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1454, in _set_optimizer
    self.optimizer = optimizers.get(optimizer)
  File "C:\mini\envs\aiml3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\optimizers.py", line 848, in get
    return deserialize(config)
  File "C:\mini\envs\aiml3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\optimizers.py", line 817, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='optimizer')
  File "C:\mini\envs\aiml3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 180, in deserialize_keras_object
    config,
```

which looks like my script isn't recognizing the optimizer. I am not sure how to instantiate it in my model.

Comment: Have you passed instantiated `rprop` into your model?

Comment: I tried running `opt = keras.optimizers.rprop(learning_rate=0.01)`, before the model, but I got the following error: `could not find function "keras.optimizers.rprop"`

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? I have a deadline coming up and I don't want such a silly issue holding back my results :(

Comment: Can you provide more details on code, so we can have a detailed look at the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem is that there is no 'rprop' optimizer in Keras. You can find a list of available optimizers here: https://keras.io/api/optimizers/

As a concrete workaround, you can use rmsprop instead. Check out [the doc](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/rmsprop/)s for an usage example.